# Subset dataframe by column value

Tags: r, dataframe

I am an inexperienced data wrangler so forgive my simple language.

I have a dataframe

```
 df
  sample1 sample2 sample3 median
1       1       2       3      2
2       2       2       5      2
3       5       4       5      5
4       5       6       5      5
5       2       6       6      6
```

and I want to take all values corresponding to unique values in the median column.

Something like this:

```
median2
[1] 1 2 3 2 2 5

median5
[1] 5 4 5 5 6 5

median6
[1] 2 6 6
```

I want to do this for a large dataframe so I don't want something like

```
median2 <- df[df$median == '2',]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
out <- by(df, df$median, function(z) unlist(subset(z, select = -median), use.names = FALSE))
out
# df$median: 2
# [1] 1 2 2 2 3 5
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# df$median: 5
# [1] 5 5 4 6 5 5
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# df$median: 6
# [1] 2 6 6
```

Realize that a `by`-class return is really just a glorified `list`, so it can be dealt with in the same ways:

```r
str(out)
# List of 3
#  $ 2: int [1:6] 1 2 2 2 3 5
#  $ 5: int [1:6] 5 5 4 6 5 5
#  $ 6: int [1:3] 2 6 6
#  - attr(*, "dim")= int 3
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
#   ..$ df$median: chr [1:3] "2" "5" "6"
#  - attr(*, "call")= language by.data.frame(data = df, INDICES = df$median, FUN = function(z) unlist(subset(z, select = -median), use.names = FALSE))
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "by"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidyverse approach.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat1 <- dat |> 
  mutate(median = paste0("median", median)) |> 
  group_by(median) |> 
  summarise(new_var = list(
    as.integer(t(cur_data()))
  )) |> 
  deframe()

dat1

# $median2
# [1] 1 2 2 2 3 5
# 
# $median5
# [1] 5 5 4 6 5 5
# 
# $median6
# [1] 2 6 6
```

**Steps:**

1. Convert the dataframe within each group of median value (denoted by `cur_data()`) to integer. Note that it was first converted to a matrix using `t()` to get the desired number order.
2. `deframe()` from `tibble` package convert a list column to a named
   list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` after unlisting the dataframe into vector.

```
cols <- grep('sample', names(df))
split(c(t(df[cols])), paste0('median', rep(df$median, each = length(cols))))

#$median2
#[1] 1 2 3 2 2 5

#$median5
#[1] 5 4 5 5 6 5

#$median6
#[1] 2 6 6
```

Comment: I am going to read and try to understand the descriptions of ```split``` and ```rep``` as I am unfamiliar with these functions but thanks a lot for your solution, it works well.